# Permission error when saving a document

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I've workflow application using 8 xpages. It was working fine upto this moment and all of sudden when saving new document for any xpage, it started giving the following error:

Unexpected runtime error

The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
Error source

Page Name:/XpNew.xsp

Exception

Error saving data source document1
Could not save the document 44F2A NotesException: Notes error: You cannot update or delete the document(s) since you are not listed as an allowable Author for this document

Even though I've manager access to the database. It is also weird that it started giving error on test and production server. I also ran compact with -c and still the same issue.
Ran Fixup and still same issue.

Answer (score 4):

In this situation, since it appears to be a core Notes exception and not anything at the XSP layer, I'd look into ACLs first. Are you manager by way of being in a group? And if so, has that group changed in any way recently, or is it specified in a secondary Directory referenced via Directory Assistance? I've had situations where the HTTP task just sort of "forgets" group membership from a secondary Directory until I restart it.

Another potential source of trouble could be the "Maximum Internet name and password" field on the database's ACL's Advanced tab - if that's set to Author, it will override whatever your real access is.

As a troubleshooting step, I'd make an XPage with this in a computed text item:

```
database.queryAccess(session.getEffectiveUserName());
```

That should return your numeric access level. Additionally, to check on the first paragraph's theory, you could add a Form or Page with a computed value of:

```
@UserNamesList
```

That will give you a list of all effective names, groups, and roles for the current user in the current database.

Answer (score 2):

There was a Authors field on Notes form with value @Username which was returning value in hierarchical form as First Name/Company.

Changed the formula to @Name([Canonicalize];@UserName) and Maximum access Level thru web kept default editor. This resolve the issue. Now it is saving documents without any issue.

Thanks everybody for help